Feature Request: Adding "Contains" Operator for Conditional Fields in Multi-Select Elements in FormBuilder
I’m working with FormBuilder and encountered a limitation when trying to conditionally display a field based on the selection from a multi-select field. for example, I need a field to appear only if the "Other" option is selected in a multi-select. However, the only relevant operator available is "equal to," which doesn’t seem to work with multi-select fields.
What We Tried:
1.Single-Select Field: The same approach works perfectly fine with a single-select field.
2.Multi-Select Field: The condition doesn't work, likely due to the lack of an operator like "contains" that could be used to check if a specific option is selected from the multi-select field.
Feature Request:
Could we get a "contains" operator (or a similar operator) that would allow conditions to check if a specific option is selected in a multi-select field? This would greatly enhance the flexibility and functionality of FormBuilder.

Welcome to CiviCRM StackExchange! If you haven't done so already, I suggest that you join the Formbuilder chat channel to discuss this: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev-afform
